# WP_Query of custom post type sorted by meta_key has unexpected results

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta, meta-query, order

I do not understand why my code outputs the events in a seemingly random order. It's not sorting by the `start_time` as I would expect.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'order_by'          => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'          => 'start_time',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'nopaging'          => true,
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );




    if($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

        print_r( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'start_time', false) ) . '<br>';

    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-08 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-17 00:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-14 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-22 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-15 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-23 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-16 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-24 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-17 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-10 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-18 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-11 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-19 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-12 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-20 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-13 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-21 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-30 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-31 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-25 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-26 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-27 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-28 19:00:00 )
Array ( [0] => 2020-01-29 19:00:00 )
```

Comment: I notice you called `wp_reset_query`, this should only be used to cleanup after `query_posts`, did you meant to call `wp_reset_postdata()`? Also this should happen inside the if statement, but after the while loop, otherwise it'll cleanup even when there's nothing to cleanup

Comment: Are you sure that there are no filters hooked to pre_get_posts that are modifying the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that it's being interpreted as a STRING type and being ordered character by character. Maybe try turning this into a meta query and forcing the DATETIME type like the example shown below:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'starttime' => array(
        'key'   => 'start_time',
        'type'  => 'DATETIME',
    )
),
'orderby' => array( 'starttime' => 'ASC' ),
```

[See WP_Query Custom Field Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

Comment: If the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS then there’s no difference how you interpret this - sorting such format as string should also work. And if you take a look at the list in question, then you’ll see it’s not sorted in alphabetical order - 20 is before 13 and 21 is after 13...

Comment: The given solution did work. Thanks for the help. I still don't get what it's doing to the string to make that not work. It's being sorted as a string but sorting as a string should work given the format.